# Trying to make an image appear upon button press - react native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I am simply trying to press a button and have an image appear. I am receiving an error that is "Attempted to assign to readonly property" This is my code.

```
export class calculateRoute extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={require('./Alexa.png')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and then this is my button code that should simply return an image on press. This code is in a different class.

```
<Button
    onPress={calculateRoute}
    title="Calculate Route"
    color="#841584"
    accessibilityLabel="Button to calculate route"
/>
```

Comment: What is the code inside of `calculateRoute`?

Comment: your problem is here `onPress={calculateRoute}` it must call a function, not a component

Comment: That is the only code within calculateRoute (the top code block). It literally just returns an image.

Comment: you are using a wrong approach

Comment: @assembler I've tried setting the calculateRoute first line to this instead: calculateRoute: function(), and it still does not work. Am I making a function incorrectly?

Comment: that is not the way it works

Comment: you only can call functions in the event listeners, that is not react, that is javascript

Comment: I'm very new to react, do you mind telling me how I exactly do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
export class calculateRoute extends Component{
  constructor () { 
    super();
    this.state = {showImage: false};
  }

  showImageFunc = () => {
     this.setState({showImage: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showImage &&
        <View>
          <Image
            style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
            source={require('./Alexa.png')} />
        </View>}
        <Button
          onPress={this.showImageFunc}
          title="Calculate Route"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Button to calculate route" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the `showImage` in the component state will tell the render when to display the image. hope it helps.

Comment: this is a raw approach, and this is the way I would do it

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work. In my default class, am I supposed to change the button code in any way? The button code was in a separate  (my default) class initially. If I remove it from there, do I just need to call the function?

Comment: It works. I can't see why it doesn't work for you. I named the component `calculateRoute` after the name of the component in your question. You can call as many components as you want, even you can have components hosted in other js files, but basically this is the way. I'm consulting the state and if `showImage` is true the render will draw your `<Image .../>`.